# Some Truffle test not executed

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, truffle

It seems like some of my truffle tests are not executed. Compilation and everything is working fine. I also get no error messages what so ever.

As Im learning dapp development with a book you can download the example code [right here](https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/gxmedia.galileo-press.de/supplements/4677/978-3-8362-6390-0.zip).
And [here](https://www.rheinwerk-verlag.de/blockchain-fuer-entwickler-grundlagen-programmierung-anwendung/) is the corresponding book.

The code that I'm referring to is in `Kap12\Kap12_Security_Truffle_Project` if I run `truffle test` only some of the tests are executed, same if I run only a specific test that wasn't executed with `truffle test`

So for example when I run `truffle test .\test\TestReentrancy.sol` the output is:

```
Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Compiling .\contracts\Delegation.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\GasSiphoningWallet.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\GasToken.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\KingOfTheEther.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\Migrations.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\Reentrancy.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\SmuggleEther.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\UnderflowToken.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\Utility.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\GasToken.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\Reentrancy.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\Utility.sol
> Compiling .\test\TestReentrancy.sol
> Artifacts written to C:\Users\KONSTA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\test--15764-W3tQRszemoJS
> Compiled successfully using:
   - solc: 0.5.0+commit.1d4f565a.Emscripten.clang



  0 passing (1ms)
```

Output: truffle version

```
Truffle v5.3.4 (core: 5.3.4)
Solidity - 0.5.0 (solc-js)
Node v14.16.1
Web3.js v1.3.5
```

Would be very helpful If someone else could test if the code works on his system.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you trying to deploy your smart contract like this. I am facing the same problem.

```
  var instance = await BrownieToken.deployed();
   
  it("Initialize contract with correct value", async ()=> {
    const tokenName = await instance.name();
    const tokenSymbol = await instance.symbol()
    assert.equal(tokenName, "BrownieToken","Token name should be BrownieToken");
    assert.equal(tokenSymbol, "BT","Token symbol should be BT");
    
  });
```

Wrap your deployment part in before. It's work for me hopes its works for u as well ;)

```
var instance;
before(async() => {
  instance = await BrownieToken.deployed();
})
```